# Sendinblue: Configuración de cabeceras (headers)

Tags: php, api, email

Quisiera saber de qué forma puedo usar las cabeceras en Sendinblue:

```
"headers" => array("Content-Type"=> "text/html; charset=UTF-8","X-param1"=> "value1", "X-param2"=> "value2","X-Mailin-custom"=>"my custom value", "X-Mailin-IP"=> "102.102.1.2", "X-Mailin-Tag" => "My tag")
```

No se para qué puedo usar estas opciones: X-param1, X-param2, X-Mailin-custom, IP, X-Mailin-Tag. Entiendo que *Mailin* es el nombre de la API de Sendinblue, pero cómo puedo usarlo para mi beneficio ya que si omito su uso también funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente lo que quieres saber está en la [documentación](https://apidocs.sendinblue.com/tutorial-sending-transactional-email/):

Sendinblue reserva las cabeceras mencionadas abajo, para proporcionar diferentes características en la plataforma:

```
Header               Description
“X-Mailin-custom” => “My custom value” Para enviar un texto personalizado.
“X-Mailin-IP”     => “102.102.1.2”  Envíe su IP dedicada que está asociada 
                      con su cuenta SMTP Sendinblue. Vamos a transmitir el correo
                      electrónico a través de este IP.
“X-Mailin-Tag”    => “My tag”   Definir etiqueta, para buscar por etiquetas.
```

> **Note:** 
>   “X-Mailin-IP” No se enviarán junto con los encabezados del correo electrónico original.
>   “X-param1″, “X-param2″, “X-Mailin-custom” and “X-Mailin-Tag” Se enviará junto con los encabezados del correo electrónico original.
>   “X-Mailin-custom” and “X-Mailin-Tag” También se enviará junto con la respuesta JSON de webhooks, cuando se produce algún evento. Además, la "X-Mailin-Tag" se recibirá como sólo "etiqueta" en la respuesta JSON.